# Configure Widget Logic to display related data using PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, widget

I have installed Widget Logic on a Wordpress site. Using is_single('this') it correctly displays the widget on the page. But, I need 
'this' to be a variable and match another variable.

What I'm looking for is the PHP equivalent of a SQL "where" clause that will match one field to another. Select x from y where a=b;

I have posts that represent a "Location" - could be London, Paris, Munich. 
I have posts that represent "Services" and can be filtered by location.
I have a widget that displays available services.

I want to dynamically filter what is displayed by the widget according to the location. If I have a Munich post, only those services available in Munich are displayed in the widget and only those services available in London are displayed on the London page.

I've tried setting Widget Logic to about 20 variations of 'field1'=='field2' or 
$field1==$field2 and is_??(??) / in_??(??) No joy.

Maybe I have the syntax wrong? or using the wrong WP conditional tag?

Answer (score 0):

Using Widget Logic for this didn't work out. The following runs in a PHP Text box widget on the WordPress page

`$fish` is the title of the post being displayed (e.g., London)

The related posts all have a 'meta-value' that includes the location (e.g., London)

```
<?php 

    $fish = get_queried_object_id(); 

    if ('$fish' != null ) {

    query_posts (array ('post_type' => array('accommodation'), 'meta_value' => $fish, 
    'orderby' => 'asc', 'showposts' => 3) );
    if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();?>

    <h4><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
    <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'thumbnail'); ?> 
    <?php the_title(); ?></a></h4>

    <?php endwhile;
    endif;

    } else {
        echo "why is this here?";
    }
    ?>
```